# How to add Share Link Menu in Custom Tabs

Tags: android, android-intent, chrome-custom-tabs

I am trying to add a new Menu Item to my ChromeCustomTabs for sharing the current url.

I know that we can add a default

```
.addDefaultShareMenuItem()
```

to our CustomTabsIntent. But I don't want to use this.

I also know how to add a menu item by creating a PendingIntent like :-

```
Intent urlIntent = new Intent();
String currentURL = urlIntent.getDataString();
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 123, shareIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Now in our builder we will be adding :-

```
.addMenuItem("Share Current Link", p);
```

The code works but return an empty value instead of the current URL.

I don't know what to put in `Intent urlIntent = new Intent(/*what to put here to get customTabs intent*/)`.
We can't put our `customIntent` here because it is not an Intent.

Comment: I flagged it as a duplicate with a link to the answer you mentioned, so it will be marked properly.